# Java Jstl foreach

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I'm having a few problems with some JSTL code. The thing is that i'm trying to compare the id of the user that logged in with the id from the reservation class which has a foreign key of the user id.And after doing that i'm trying to populate the page with update links based on the reservation id.

Here's the code of what i tried but i can't find a way to make it work.

```
<table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Reservation Id</th>
                    <th>Data CheckIn</th>
                    <th>Data CheckOut</th>
                    <th>Numar Persoane</th>
                    <th>Numar Camere</th>
                    <th>Action</th>

                        <%
                        List<ReservationBean> theReserv = (List<ReservationBean>) request.getAttribute("RESERVATION_LIST");
                        %>
                        <% int userId = (Integer) request.getSession().getAttribute("userId"); %>

                    <c:forEach var="tempReservation" items="${RESERVATION_LIST}"> 
                    <!--  set up a link for each res -->
                            <c:url var="tempLink" value="UserControllerServlet">
                                <c:param name="command" value="LOAD"/>
                                <c:param name="reservationId" value="${tempReservation.reservationId}"/>
                            </c:url>

                            <c:url var="deleteLink" value="UserControllerServlet">
                                <c:param name="command" value="DELETE"/>
                                <c:param name="reservationId" value="${tempReservation.reservationId}"/>
                            </c:url> 

                    </c:forEach>  


                    <% for(ReservationBean res : theReserv){ 
                    /*  int userId = (Integer) request.getSession().getAttribute("userId"); */
                             if(userId == res.getUserId()){ %>          
                                <tr>
                                    <td> <%= res.getReservationId() %> </td>
                                    <td> <%= res.getDataCheckin() %> </td>
                                    <td> <%= res.getDataCheckout() %> </td> 
                                    <td> <%= res.getNrPersoane()%> </td>
                                    <td> <%= res.getNrCamere() %> </td>
                                    <td><a href="${tempLink}">Update</a>
                                        |
                                    <a href="${deleteLink}"
                                    onclick="if(!(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this reservation?'))) return false">Delete</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            <%}%>
                        <%}%>  
                </tr>
            </table>
```

In the second for i'm comparing the id of the user that logged in with the id of the user from the reservation class but of course the updated links will contain the last value of the first for and i don't know how to do what i did in pure java with JSTL to have only one for and get the correct values of the update link or delete ones.Do you guys have any clue on how to do that?

Comment: use the `c:forEach` not only to generate the links, but also to create the `tr` tags. Use `c:if` to compare the userId with the reservation's userId

Comment: Where is RESERVATION_LIST being set?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried something like this

```
<table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Reservation Id</th>
                    <th>Data CheckIn</th>
                    <th>Data CheckOut</th>
                    <th>Numar Persoane</th>
                    <th>Numar Camere</th>
                    <th>Action</th>

                        <%
                        List<ReservationBean> theReserv = (List<ReservationBean>) request.getAttribute("RESERVATION_LIST");
                        %>
                        <% int userId = (Integer) request.getSession().getAttribute("userId"); %>

                    <c:forEach var="tempReservation" items="${RESERVATION_LIST}"> 
                    <!--  set up a link for each res -->

                        <c:if test="${tempReservation.userId}" == userId >
                            <c:url var="tempLink" value="UserControllerServlet">
                                <c:param name="command" value="LOAD"/>
                                <c:param name="reservationId" value="${tempReservation.reservationId}"/>
                            </c:url>

                            <c:url var="deleteLink" value="UserControllerServlet">
                                <c:param name="command" value="DELETE"/>
                                <c:param name="reservationId" value="${tempReservation.reservationId}"/>
                            </c:url> 
                                <tr>
                                    <td>${tempReservation.reservationId}</td>
                                    <td>${tempReservation.dataCheckin}</td>
                                    <td>${tempReservation.dataCheckout}</td>
                                    <td>${tempReservation.nrPersoane}</td>
                                    <td>${tempReservation.nrCamere}</td>
                                    <td><a href="${tempLink }">Update</a>
                                        |
                                        <a href="${deleteLink}"
                                        onclick="if(!(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this student?'))) return false">Delete</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                        </c:if> 
                    </c:forEach>
```

But that if condition doesn't work or i don't know how to compare jstl code with java code

Edit2: I made it work! You had to compare it something like this

```
<c:if test="${tempReservation.userId == userId }">
```

Thanks for help!